# tar unix not changing directory

Tags: shell, directory, wildcards, tar

I am executing a tar command to compress files which are present in another directory.

I executed following command:

```
tar -czf /backupmnt/abc.tar.gz -C /backupmnt/statusService/ *
```

I want to create abc.tar.gz file in `/backupmnt` which should include all files in `/backupmnt/statusService/` directory, but I am getting below error:

```
tar: components: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

`components` is present in current directory from where I am executing the command. Below are the contents of `/backupmnt/statusService`

```
SS-01:/ # ls /backupmnt/statusService
MJ.netact.xml.tar.gz      gmoTemp_fm.tar.gz  mr.properties.tar.gz  probe.properties.tar.gz  relay_logs.tar.gz  ss_logs.tar.gz  tomcat_conf.tar.gz
esymac_config.txt.tar.gz  gmoTemp_pm.tar.gz  o2ml.tar.gz           probes_logs.tar.gz       ss_conf.tar.gz     ss_pm.tar.gz    tomcat_logs.tar.gz
```

I am not able to get where I am wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`*` is expanded by the shell before `tar` gets executed. So, making `tar` change the directory invalidates the arguments that `*` expanded into. You can simply tell `tar` to compress the directory instead:

```
tar -czf /backupmnt/abc.tar.gz -C /backupmnt/statusService/ .
```

The `.` represents the current directory, which will change when `tar` changes directories. This will result in hidden files (those beginning with `.`) being included in the archive.

Answer (score 2):

Why do not use explicit directory change?

```
cd /backupmnt/statusService && tar -czf /backupmnt/abc.tar.gz *
```

Or you can use relative paths:

```
cd /
tar -czf /backupmnt/abc.tar.gz backupmnt/statusService1/* backupmnt/statusService2/* backupmnt/statusService3/*
```

Which can be even better solution as you will keep files separated in folders and avoid overwrite of duplicated filenames

Comment: This one I was using in shell script.-C option I am using because I have to add multiple files located at various locations. doing `cd` may lead to rejection of my script

Comment: On the next add you can use update command instead of create. And you can use relative paths, see my edited answer

Comment: 1 problem I got in this, instead of taking files only, it has taken them with complete directory structure inside tar.gz file

Comment: True, you will get the directory structure inside. And IMHO this will be better (to have overview from where is the file). Of course you can create few different tar files per directory. I use in my practice both ways

Answer (score 1):

`-C` is not a portable option anyway. It's a GNU option not a UNIX one.

`tar` is no longer specified by the Single UNIX Specification anyway as there's so much difference between the implementations. It has `pax` to create archives portably.

You could do:

```
pax -ws '|.*//||' /backupmnt/statusService//. /some/other/dir//./*.ext |
  xz > file.tar.xz
```

(`xz`/`gzip` are not specified by POSIX).

That is use `//.` to mark which part of the paths are to be stripped.